# converting date and time without delimiter to date time with delimiter in sql server

Tags: sql-server-2008, datetime, formatting

I would like to convert date(without any delimiter ex. 31012015) and time(without any delimiter ex.0144) to date and time with delimiter. i.e.

31012015 => 31/01/2015 (dd/mm/yyyy)

0144 => 01:44 (hh:mm)

I tried various option in sql server (using various [date-time format](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/az4se3k1(v=vs.110).aspx)) but couldn't able to find out its solution.

Answer (score 1):

try this

```
select replace(CONVERT(VARCHAR(10), GETDATE(), 103),'/','') as date_format, 
left(replace(CONVERT(VARCHAR(10), GETDATE(), 108),':',''),4) timeformat
```

Answer (score 0):

Since you only seem to care about the string representation of the value, you could use [`STUFF`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188043(v=sql.100).aspx):

```
SELECT STUFF(@time, 3, 0, ':') as NewTime,
  STUFF(STUFF(@date, 3, 0, '/'), 6, 0, '/') as NewDate
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want your DATETIME without any delimiter, you can try this:

```
SELECT
replace(convert(varchar, getdate(),112),'/','') + replace(convert(varchar, getdate(),108),':','')
```